# Opening Creo file in student edition

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, cad

Is it possible to open a part created using Creo commercial edition in the student edition ? I tried this but it doesn’t seem to work. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: See if you can get someone to read it for you and save it as IGES, then import that. Perhaps a friend in industry that has access to CREO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "professional" version has more features, so the parts have extra information that the student version won't be able to read or convert.

So, You will need the "professional" version - at least for complicated parts. If it was just a simple bar it would likely open.

You can understand them protecting their software...